# Progressbar overlapping at smaller displays (responsive design issue )

Tags: html, css, responsive

Hi people when i use a device with a smaller display. The progressbar would overlap the main area (like in the picture below). Please help me. I am a absolute beginner.

[Progressbar overlapping at small displays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/socXK.png)

```html
<body id="top">
<img STYLE="position:relative; TOP:4px; LEFT:77px; WIDTH:50px; HEIGHT:50px" id="img1" src="images/cog1.png" alt="cog1">
<script>rotateAnimation("img1",30);</script>       <--- image above progressbar

<div id='progress-bar'>
  <div id='progress-now'></div>     <----- Progressbar
</div>

<div id="cv" class="instaFade">
 <div class="mainDetails">        <----- this is the main area
```

Greetings from austria. Thanks !

Comment: Please include the JavaScript needed for you snippet to run.

Answer (score 0):

For the progress bar which is overlapping, give it a style attribute, left: 20%.

Dont use left/right px. It will give the element fixed position